# Change Language on Openweather API

Tags: javascript, php, api

i'll try to be quick on the question. I want to use a weather forecast for Real Estate, using this [codepen](https://codepen.io/AdventureBear/pen/PwmoMd?depth=everything&limit=all&order=popularity&page=2&q=weather&show_forks=false)

```js
var weatherData = {
  city: document.querySelector ("#city"),
  weather: document.querySelector ("#weather"),
  temperature: document.querySelector("#temperature"),
  temperatureValue: 0,
  units: "°C"
  
};

function roundTemperature(temperature){
   temperature = temperature.toFixed(1);
   return temperature;
  }

function switchUnits (){
  
  if (weatherData.units == "°C") {
    weatherData.temperatureValue = roundTemperature(weatherData.temperatureValue * 9/5 + 32);
    weatherData.units = "°F";
  
} else {
  weatherData.temperatureValue = roundTemperature ((weatherData.temperatureValue -32) * 5/9);
    weatherData.units = "°C";  
}

  weatherData.temperature.innerHTML = weatherData.temperatureValue + weatherData.units + " ";
}


function getLocationAndWeather(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      var position = {
        latitude: response.latitude,
        longitude: response.longitude
      };
      var cityName = response.city;

      var weatherSimpleDescription = response.weather.simple;
      var weatherDescription = response.weather.description;
      var weatherTemperature = roundTemperature(response.weather.temperature);

      weatherData.temperatureValue = weatherTemperature;

      loadBackground(position.latitude, position.longitude, weatherSimpleDescription);
      weatherData.city.innerHTML = cityName;
      weatherData.weather.innerHTML =  ", " + weatherDescription;
      weatherData.temperature.innerHTML = weatherTemperature + weatherData.units;
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(err){
      alert("Could not complete the request");
    }, false);

    xhr.open("GET", "https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/getlocationandweather.php?owapikey=e2db5b0453a25a492e87ad8b03046a7c&units=metric", true);
    xhr.send();
  }
  else{
    alert("Unable to fetch the location and weather data.");
  }           
}


function loadBackground(lat, lon, weatherTag) {
  var script_element = document.createElement('script');

  script_element.src = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1452866c8cea54acd0075022ef573a07&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&accuracy=1&tags=" + weatherTag + "&sort=relevance&extras=url_l&format=json";
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_element);
}

function jsonFlickrApi(data){
  if (data.photos.pages > 0){
    //var randomPhotoId = parseInt(data.photos.total);
    var photo = data.photos.photo[Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(data.photos.photo.length))];
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + photo.url_l + "')";
    document.querySelector("#image-source").setAttribute("href", "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + photo.owner + "/" + photo.id);
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/images/default.jpg')";
    document.querySelector("#image-source").setAttribute("href", "https://www.flickr.com/photos/superfamous/310185523/sizes/o/");
  }
}

getLocationAndWeather();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  color: #fff;
  background: #888;
  bacground-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section {

   min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  
}

p {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

a{
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

#temperature {
   text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0.05em dotted white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 id= "city">Weather Web App</h1>
  <p> <a id="temperature" href="#" onclick="switchUnits(); return false;" title ="Click to switch between metric and impreial units"></a><span id = "weather"> by Shazam (tutorial from @fourtonfish)</p>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>Powered by <a href="http://flickr.com/services/api/">Flickr</a> and <a href="http://openweathermap.org">Openweathermap.org</a>.
    
  Created by <a href="https://twitter.com/steelcitycoach">@steelcitycoach</a>. <a id="image-source" href="#">Image source</a>.</p>
  
</footer>
```

to generate different results with PHP, like the Adidas Ultraboost TR site i saw..

The problem: I can't change the "description" to portuguese (pt-br). I've already seen the OpenWeather documentation, who told me to include "&lang=pt" on the URL, but it didn't work. To complete the problem, this is the site of the owner of this code, but i don't have acess to [this page](https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/getlocationandweather.php), who i suppose that i could change some setting or something like that. If you run the snippet, this is what i can change on the response:

"weather": {
    "simple": "Clear",
   -> "description": "clear sky", <-

So, there is two ways i think you could help me:

1. Tell me a way to change "clear sky" to "céu limpo" or the portguese equivalent to that WITHOUT the need to change de php file:
2. Give me a light to change the responde with php. Example: if i receive the "clear sky" response, i change it to "céu limpo" or whatever i want.

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: The OpenWeatherMap API seems to be CORS enabled, so you can make the request to it yourself directly from your client-side JavaScript. There is no need to go via this server-side script - which seems to be offered as a tutorial only anyways, so using that on a production site for a commercial(?) real estate business would be stealing traffic from someone else effectively, because every request to your site by a visitor would mean a request to their site as well.

Comment: I am aware of that, but i'm only testing it. If it works like i expect, i will contract a agency to develop it profissionally for the company i work. Thanks for that!

Comment: Well in that case, I guess for now you could fake it (if that helps you go on with developing, and won't be used in production or on any larger scale), because from looking at that function, it only passes three specific parameters on to the API, but neglects to apply proper URL encoding to them - so while adding `&lang=pt` won't work, you can smuggle that in as part of the value of one of the other parameters, if you URL-encode the `&` on your end: https://fourtonfish.com/tutorials/weather-web-app/getlocationandweather.php?owapikey=e2db5b0453a25a492e87ad8b03046a7c&units=metric%26lang=pt

Comment: I've contacted the site owner, and he gave me acess to the php file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a translation service to translate the description into whatever language you want.

For example, here's a JavaScript function that takes a string, calls the Google Translate API, and returns the translated string in Portuguese:

```
function translateDescription(description) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=pt&dt=t&q=" + description, false);
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    return response[0][0][0];
}
```

I forked and modified your CodePen a bit to do this. Basically, on line 46 where you have `var weatherDescription`, I call the `translateDescription` function above with the description string returned by the OpenWeatherMap API.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMwWoR